# a question related to sqlite

Tags: iphone

hi i have 1 update query in db
and it is by use  of sqlite

```
int success = SQLITE_STEP(insert_statement);
```

i get success value 21

what s meaningof it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the description of the return values as seen in http://www.sqlite.org/c_interface.html
it mean's "/* Library used incorrectly */"